# Register Camera Device like Snap Camera in MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, camera, avfoundation

If you have ever used Snap Camera or ManyCam, these are apps get installed in Desktop environments, and register some sort of extra camera device to the system. Allowing apps like Skype, Google Hangouts, or pretty much any other video call app to recognize it.

I wonder how to do that? 
How can I make a MacOS app, that registers a device camera across the system, so that I can feed video frames to it, and be fetched by any other third party app.

Does apple provides some sort of API or SDK for this ? AVFoundation or something ?

Comment: got answer? Any luck? I'm also looking for something like this...

Comment: @KarthickSelvam negative. I stopped trying :((

Comment: Came here while trying to get Snap Camera working. I found out it's a DAL plugin if that helps any future spelunkers. Still can't get Snap Camera to work though haha.